# Need Guidance to develop a linux OS

Tags: linux

I like to develop a Linux OS , what are all the languages i should learn !!

I have basic idea of C and C ++

Pls suggest me

Comment: I think you may be biting off more than you can chew, trying to run before you can walk, _and_ jumping in at the deep end.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you trying to create an OS from scratch, to behave like linux? Or are you just planning on creating a distribution of linux?

Comment: May be you should consider starting with something smaller, simpler and more useful than an OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ is a good start for that.

Comment: Ok :) can u suggest where should i start !!

I dont have any idea abt this but it is my desire to develop  a OS

Comment: C and http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ is a good start for that.//

Thanks bro i was looking for a stuff like this :)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget Assembly, you need to build a common set of assembly routines, to boot the machine and to abstract and unify hardware and processor specific features such as MMU, Mode switching, processing interupts etc. The assembly routines will have to conform to an ABI of your choosing.

C, C++ come next :D

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with `tur1ng` - LinuxFromScratch is a good basis for a nice *NIX OS. I would also look into Gentoo as well. If you want to start with a very basic system, another good option would be Zenwalk Core Edition http://www.zenwalk.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=32

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks all for ur help :) .. i believe i will get a clear idea where I have to step in to reach it !!

May be years it will take :)